# Why is a space allowed between minus and a number?

Tags: ruby

These are expected:

```
-3 # => -3
0 - 3 # => -3
```

But what is happening here:

```
- 3 # => -3
```

My first thoughts was `-` is a method on the implied `self`, i.e. `self.-(3)`, so defined on `Kernel` or `Object`. But trying this results in `NoMethodError: undefined method`.

Comment: sorry typo, fixed.

Comment: `-` is also an unary operator, e.g., http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html

Comment: By the way: you were actually right, but you were looking in the wrong place. `-` *is* a method, but it is obviously being applied to `3` here, not `self`. And the method is actually called `-@`, not `-`, because `-` is already used for the binary operator. That's why it's `+@` and `-@`, but `~` and `!` (there is no binary `~` or `!` operator, only the unary ones).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby has a pretty forgiving syntax and allows things like this. That's parsed as a unary minus operator. It negates whatever's on the right hand side.

Also similar:

```
-(3)
# => -3
-(-(-3))
# => -3
- (3)
# => -3
```

It's similar to how you *can* omit braces on method calls: `foo x` is valid, but `foo(x)` is implied. You can also do `foo (x)` though that can lead to ambiguity so it's generally frowned upon.

As Dave Newton points out, internally this is actually:

```
3.send(:-@)
```

Comment: Would I be right in thinking then that an unary operator is called on the object on the right hand side, the argument? They are treated specially by Ruby.

Comment: It's to do with how the parse tree interprets this symbol and which object it passes the method to. Most programming languages have a concept of unary and binary operators. `1+2` is `1.send(:+, 2)` but `+1` is `1.send(:+@)`. It's up to the parser to make the call as to which operator type is employed. The interpretation is often highly context sensitive.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that the `-` in `-11` is just part of the literal and not a call to `-@` at all, `- 11` (note the space) however is `11.send(:-@)`.

Comment: Also, since I'm nitpicking anyway, `foo (x)` works because the expression `(x)` is equivalent to just `x` but `foo (x, y)` is a SyntaxError (i.e. the parentheses in `f(x)` are method-calling-parentheses but in `f (x)` they're expression-grouping-parentheses).

Comment: `x -- y` also works, it is equivalent to `x - - y`, i.e. `x.-(y.-@())`. The really cruel thing is that the whitespace between the unary operator and its operand may actually be a linebreak, so `x++\ny` is perfectly valid, looks like `x++` and does something completely different, namely `x.+(y.+@())`. (And since the linebreak is valid, *if* there is an error *at all*, it will be reported on the *next* line.)

Comment: Funnily enough I asked the question because I wrote `x =- y` instead of `x -= y` and was getting an unexpected value in `x`, namely negative `y` instead of subtraction of `y` from `x`.